# How to hide specific jqueryui tab based on some condition?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on an application in which a selected tab should not visible to specific users.My code is

```
<div id="tabs">
      <ul>
           <li><a href="#divLogTickets">Log Tickets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#divOpenTickets">Open Tickets</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="divLogTickets" runat="server" style="padding: 25px;">

      </div>
</div>

if (getUserRole(Convert.ToString(Session["UserId"])) == "HR")
{
   //hide tab
}
```

How to hide a specific tab based on specific user role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `id` and `runat="server"` attributes to the elements that you want to access from the code behind and set the `.Visible` property in code behind.

For example if you want to hide `Log Tickets` tab, here's what your aspx code should look like:

```
<div id="tabs">
      <ul>
           <li id="liLogTickets" runat="server"><a href="#divLogTickets">Log Tickets</a></li>
           <li><a href="#divOpenTickets">Open Tickets</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="divLogTickets" runat="server" style="padding: 25px;">

      </div>
</div>
```

Then set the visibility of `liLogTickets` and `divLogTickets` in code behind:

```
if (getUserRole(Convert.ToString(Session["UserId"])) == "HR")
{
    //hide Log Tickets tab
    liLogTickets.Visible = false;
    divLogTickets.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(selector).hide();` method [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

For eg:

```
if (getUserRole(Convert.ToString(Session["UserId"])) == "HR")
{
   //hide tab
   $('#userId').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the validations , i.e. you have validated that this particular user you want to hide it from (as you have mentioned in your code) further you can use the hide() function to hide that particular element.

```
$('#Id_of_Element').hide();
```